# MySQL won't start after 5.5 security upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, upgrade

I have the MySQL data directory running in a non-standard location on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. Last night it received a security upgrade and now will not start. The error message is

`Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm'`

More worrying is that when I go into the data directory there are now two directories call "mysql". When I cd in, all of my databases seem to be missing. I have no idea if I am in the old or new directory as they both seem to have the created on date.